# Xamarin Forms - Pins/Marker Position/Size

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I'm coming to ask a double question because google can't give me any answer about it.

I have a project about pins/marker customization  => **[MapPinsProject](https://github.com/Emixam23/XamarinByEmixam23/tree/master/Detailed%20Part/Controls/Map/MapPinsProject)**.

So, My `CustomPin` has a property `public Position Position { get; set; }` and when I zoom, it seems barely ok, but if I'm zooming out, the image is moving out of the position I gave, I think that the Pin position is the center of the image and not  the bot of my custom pin image..

However, the image, on google map (as example), is resizing about the zoom level.

**So, what is the way to get, at the same time, the bottom of my custom image at the right location and the good scale/size for the image?**

Thank in advance !

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this has to do with the anchor point of your custom pushpin. If the anchor point isn't correct, the pushpin will appear to drift away and towards your coordinate as you zoom. I don't have a Xamrin specific example, but here is information on different ways that this is often corrected in Bing Maps: https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/correcting-anchoring-pushpins-to-the-map/

Comment: Thank for this answer, however, how can I resize the Pin? Because I don't know on what can be based my calcul of the anchor :/

Comment: Taking a look at the UWP project, if you open the CustomMapRender, the UpdatePins method creates a map icon by the looks of it. You can do one of two things, use any other UI control (i.e. image, grid...) and pass it into the nativeMap.children property and then use a margin to offset the image accordingly. If you want to continue to use the MapIcon class, you can set it's NormalizedAnchorPoint  to offset it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapicon.aspx

Comment: Hi ! I then did it, however, I still have the problem about the size.. the icon get too big when I unzoom :/

Comment: The pixel size of the pushpin shouldn't be changing.